# Azure Service Bus GetBody<Stream> encoding cannot be determined

Tags: c#-4.0, azureservicebus

I'm trying to get a BrokeredMessage from AzureServiceBus in a .NET client and choose how to deal with the message based on the type of message coming in, but ContentType and other message properties are not set.

My test message sending looks like this:

```
            var client = 
QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
        var message = new BrokeredMessage("test");
            client.Send(message);
```

My code to receive is using GetBody so that I can inspect the serialized data and decide how to deal with it:

```
var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
                       string s = null;
                       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                       {
                           s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                       }
```

The problem is that "s" above ends up with what looks like it should be XML created from a DataContractSerializer, but it is strangely encoded. I've tried many encodings on the receiving side and none seem to get me valid xml.  Example results:

```
@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�test
```

I see the serialization namespace and what looks like it should start with <string, but as you can see I'm getting control characters.  Does any one know how I can try to get the serialized data here as valid XML so I can dynamically handle it?

TIA for any help.

To be really clear I want to test the body so I can do something like:

if (BodyIsString(s)) { do something }
if (BodyIsPerson(s)) { do something else }

If I could getbody twice this would be really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean Feldman mentioned when send message is string type we could use

```
var body = message.GetBody<string>();
```

to get message body, after I decompile the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.dll then get the code:

```
 public T GetBody<T>()
    {
      if (typeof (T) == typeof (Stream))
      {
        this.SetGetBodyCalled();
        return (T) this.BodyStream;
      }
      if (!this.bodyObjectDecoded || this.bodyObject == null)
        return this.GetBody<T>((XmlObjectSerializer) new DataContractBinarySerializer(typeof (T)));
      this.SetGetBodyCalled();
      return (T) this.bodyObject;
    }
```

I find that if the send message 
is not Stream type it will be DataContractBinarySerializer. so we also could get the message body with following way

```
var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
var messageBody = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string)).ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(stream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max));
```

From the decompiled code we could know that if we send the stream message, we could get the message body with the way you mentioned.

Send stream message code :

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test stream");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
client.Send(new BrokeredMessage(stream));
```

then receive message as you mentioned it should work:

```
var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
                       string s = null;
                       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                       {
                           s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                       }
```

**Edit** :According to update question:

> If I could getbody twice this would be really easy.

we could clone the BrokerMessage

```
var newMessage = receiveMessage.Clone();
```

**Edit2:**

We also can get the message Properties to know the body type if we set it during sending. Take **Label** for example:

```
 var message = new BrokeredMessage(object);
 message.Label = "Type of message body";
 client.Send(message);
```

While we receive the message we could get the message **Label** value then select the corresponding way to get the body.

Comment: Your answer here is helpful but doesn't quite get me there.  If I use the stream directly with the data contract serializer as you suggest I can get the string, but if I copy the stream so i can try as a string, or as other like:
                          
                           using (Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream())
                           {
                               stream.CopyTo(stream2);
                               var messageBody = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string)).ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(stream2, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max));

Comment: According to your update, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Tom, that will work for me, appreciate the helpful replies.  With your decompiled code I was closer, and with the suggestion to clone I will be able to do what I want.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You passed your payload as a string

`var message = new BrokeredMessage("test");`

therefore it was serialized as a string. Upon receive you should get the body as a string as well in the following manner:

`var body = message.GetBody<string>();`

You would use `Stream` if you'd actually construct your brokered message using a stream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I'm trying to do is inspect the body so that I can determine it is a string.  The test send is just an example.  The messages on the queue will have different types: string, Person, etc.  Your solution assumes I know it is a string, but I do not.

Comment: Well, with the update to your question is a slightly different problem. And yes, cloning would help. But what if it's not a string? Then you need to clone per each test. Frankly, at that point I smell something in the design and would say it's the sender responsibility to stamp the message with a header which tells what type of body it is.

Comment: @SeanFeldman completely agree that it would make more sense for the sender to specify type. That's cleaner and more reliable. It'd be nice to be able to have a cleaner implementation of a smart backend without the try / catch or interrogating the stream fetched body.  I mean clearly the first part of the actual serialized content shows the type, but. I can't seem to take that as byte[] and get it to deserialize correctly.